# how can put true in match.success C#?

Tags: c#

I trying to put true in match.success but not work

please help me

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var match.Success=true;
        while (match.Success)
        {
            code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You really need to be more specific when asking questions. We have to guess at what `match.Success` actually is here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's not possible cause it's a `read-only` property. See [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.success(v=vs.110).aspx)

Not sure what's your context in the posted code but looks like you are trying to force set `true` and use that in `while` loop. In such case why can't you directly say

```
while (true)
{
    code
}
```